# anything similar to set_preferences for calabash ios

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios, calabash-android

I am testing a scenario where on third visit the 'give the feedback' form appears.

For android I've used the set_preference method to set the variable ( 'VisitCount' => 2) .Then I am just visiting once and then I see the 'give the feedback' form.This works perfectly fine.

However for iOS I didn't find anything similar . Can anyone suggest how I can do this.

Comment: I got the answer on my own. Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please post the answer here and then accept your own answer?  I'm sure it'd be appreciated by anyone who finds your question when they're looking for help.